# Using WinInet to download an image with a URL

Tags: c++, wininet

I'm working on developing a kind-of web scraper using WinInet.

Effectively, the program takes some input and will try to download all the pictures/videos on a certain page (.jpg, .png, .webm, etc.).

How can I, with an image URL, download said image using the WinInet library?  I see download files on FTP but I don't think that applies here.

I tried using LibCurl but couldn't figure out how to get it working using Visual Studio 2013.

Thanks a lot